# Stake Labels is not center aligned

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Hi I am ploting a column chart but unable to center aligned the stakelabel i am attaching the screenshot for reference
[image: Screenshot]

The second number in the stacklabels is left aligned when i am making it center aligned its working fine but after refresh the graph the align will remain left align. How to fix it.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        var chart = {
            type: 'column',
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false,
            marginRight: '4',
            borderWidth: 0
        };
        var title = {
            text: 'Top 5 Buyers'
        };
        var subtitle = {
            text: '<a style="font-size:smaller;text-decoration: underline;cursor: pointer" href="#">Investors</a>',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            align: 'center',
            X: -5,
            color: 'blue'
        };
        var xAxis = {
            categories: ['Investor Mutual <br>Australian share fund', 'Mr Grills T greyar', 'California Public employees', 'State street Global Advisors', 'MLC Limited'],
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineWidth: 0,
            //lineColor: 'transparent',
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0
        };
        var yAxis = {
            min: 0,
            max: 120,
            endOnTick: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                verticalAlign: 'center',
                align: 'center',
                x: -10,
                y: -15,
                formatter: function() {
                    //return this.axis.chart.xAxis[0].categories[this.x] + '<br>$' + this.total;
                    return "10,124100"+ '<br>$' + this.total;
                },
            }



        };
        var tooltip = {
            // pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
            //  shared: true,
            valueDecimals: 2,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<div> ' + this.point.name.toUpperCase() + '<br />' + 'SHARES:       ' + '<br />' + '<b>%IC: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2) + ' %' + '</b>' + '<br />' + 'NO. INVESTORS: ' + '</div>';
            }
        };
        var plotOptions = {
            column: {
                datalabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                
            cursor: 'pointer'
        },

            series: {
                stacking: 'percent',
            pointWidth: 50,
            groupPadding: 1
            }
    };
    var credits = {
        enabled: false
    };
    var series = [{
        color: '#02C362',
        showInLegend: false,
        data: [293534023, 2817040, 901773, 690000, 560556],
       //  data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
        // pointPadding: 0.8,
        // pointPlacement: -0.2,
    }, {
        Color: '#004C99',
        showInLegend: false,
        data: [21549709, 11980000, 46071, 750000, 609300],
       // data: ['3', '4', '4', '2', '5'],
        // pointPadding: 0.8,
        // pointPlacement:-0.2,
    }];

    var json = {};
    json.chart = chart;
    json.title = title;
    json.xAxis = xAxis;
    json.yAxis = yAxis;
    json.tooltip = tooltip;
    json.plotOptions = plotOptions;
    json.credits = credits;
    json.series = series;
    json.subtitle = subtitle;
    $('#container').highcharts(json);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz9d1vL0/17/)

Comment: What is the b21 value here: `x: b21` ? Also, `marginLeft: '-13px'` is going to shift everything to the left. Can you set up a working fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the above code snippet. Please refer the same and help me out. I am plotting the graph based on the dynamic value(ajax call) so it might not work in fiddle. Thank You

Comment: OK, if I understand correctly, based on various criteria you are pushing your `stackLabel` anywhere from 8 to 70 pixels to the left. Which would seem to explain why the labels are showing more to the left...? If you don't feel that explains it, you'll need to come up with a static example that you can put into a fiddle or other live demo.

Comment: I have added a working fiddle link please go through it and help me out.

Comment: Am I missing something? As I said in my last two comments, you are explicitly telling the chart to move the labels to the left, with `y: -15`.  If I remove that line, the labels are centered: https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/bz9d1vL0/18/  Can you elaborate on what about that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @ManishGupta To get the data labels alignment from your image you could use HTML dataLabels - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jku2zsra/ Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Briggs,Even though if we remove y:-15 , the 2nd number in the stack labels are not getting centered, the issue is with the second number in the stacklabels. In our project , defined x and y to some number shows the text aligh center but everytime we need to refresh the page. How we can referesh the chart on load?